# How to get the link to the index page to appear

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have started using jsdoc with jaguarjs-jsdoc to generate documentation for my API using node. It is working quite well and I can even use a readme.md file to generate the index page but I can't seem to get the link to the index page to appear in the top left above the search bar [see example site](http://davidshimjs.github.io/jaguarjs/doc/index.html).

The command I am running looks like this.

`$ ./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc ./README.md ./app/ -r -t ./node_modules/jaguarjs-jsdoc/ -d docs`

The only tags I am using in the api so far are @namespace, @function, and @member. Like I said, they seem to be generating fine. The link is only a little thing but it is annoying me.

Any Ideas?

Comment: also, both jsdoc (v3.4.0) and jaguarjs-jsdoc (v0.0.1) have been installed locally using npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only way but I did find a solution. You can include a config in the generate command.

```
jsdoc -t `path to template` -c `path to config` `files to include`
```

In that template, you can provide an application name

```
}
  "templates": {
    "applicationName": "The Name",
    ...more configs
  },
  ...more configs
}
```

That name will appear in the link to the index page in the top right. The link itself is always generated but not much use if it is empty.